# At the basement window relatively much water penetrates in rainy weather. The easiest way to fix this?

Tags: basement, dehumidifier

I have long wondered why my dehumidifier filters so much water in the air.

I have a small window and when it rains a lot of water gets in. I have seen this only now, because before a rack was there.

[image]

I have very limited manual skills, would like to know what is the easiest way to fix this or workaround?

Update, after comments.

- Pics from ground level / from outside
- house was built 1960, totally renovated last year, I also moved in last year

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a picture of the outside too? Also, how old is the house and how long have you lived in it?

Comment: Can you post pics of the outside of that window? Look around the bottom of the window on the outside, there should be caulk between the window frame and masonry to seal it, perhaps it has aged and cracked. Also open the window and post a pic of the bottom part of the frame. Is there a puddle of water right in front of the window due to the slope being in the wrong direction?

Comment: how does the water get there ? what is on the outside, where is the ground level. need more info

Comment: and the basement window is under that grid

Comment: OK, ok, and the opening is to provide some light to the window.  Now is there some kind of drain in front of the window. How high is the window of the ground ? The assumption is the rain colects in front of widow and leaks inisde.

Comment: You're going to have to remove that grate and look inside the hole to see the outside of the window.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have a rainwater drain going right into your house. What the heck? I would fill the entire thing with concrete and be done with it. Does it serve a purpose?

Comment: Possible that is an escape/egress window required for the basement.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but look at the size of it, specifically from the outside. I don't think most adult men could fit out of that. My next thought was an air vent type thing but still, seems like a terrible design. Retrofit perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep that window you have few options.

The leak could be between window frame and wall, or between frame and the window seals.

It looks like it is some kind of window you can open. That is where it would leak if there is water pudle outside.

You can try to seal it from outside (between the wall and window frame. But that will not stop the leak on the window seal, where it opens.

You can eliminate the water build up in front of the window.

Or you can replace the window with a type that does not open, so you only have to seal between the wall and the frame.

Last not least. Take look how high is the water level when it rains hard. Now build a "hoover dam" in front of it. Probably an inch or two high out of bricks.